# Deploying sveltkit to vercel with Arcgis JS SDK

Tags: javascript, vercel, sveltekit, arcgis-js-api

I'm attempting to deploy a my first sveltekit project to vercel but keep running into issues that I can't figure out. I'm using the arcgis js sdk which has to be used in a different way to most modules, so I think that may be causing the issues, so any help is appreciated. Everything does work locally even when running the command "vercel dev"

I created a component with the map and I import it in +page.svelte this way:

```
onMount(async () => {
          const module = await import("../components/EsriMap.svelte");
          EsriMap = module.default;
        });
```

This is the error I initially got when deploying:

```
Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "@arcgis/core/map" from "/vercel/path0/src/components/EsriMap.svelte".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to build.rollupOptions.external`
```

If I add this:

```
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    build: {

        rollupOptions: {
          external: ['@arcgis/core/map']
        }
      }
});
```

it deploys without error, but nothing displays in the preview and I see this error in the console:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: The specifier “@arcgis/core/map” was a bare specifier, but was not remapped to anything. Relative module specifiers must start with “./”, “../” or “/”.
```

Comment: I don't know your problem, but directory structure is probably important here.  I am surprised you're not loading your component through the `$lib/components` (I assume you have something like that).  I'm also confused why you're loading this asynchronously

Comment: @possum I've moved it there and still get the same error. There's some issue with this library where it can't be run server side, so this is how I've seen it loaded and the only way I've gotten it working.